# Calling FirstName from dbo.Employee from Foreign Key

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I want to call the FirstName from my table Employee using Foreign Key from table Transaction() and view it on a dataTable on a partial view. This is my short DB diagram:
[image: DB Diagram]

This is how I call the datatable:
Index View

```
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div id="caTable"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    FetchCashAdvanceTransaction();

});

function FetchCashAdvanceTransaction() {
    var model = $('#caTable');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Transaction/GetOpenCATransaction',
        contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    })
        .success(function (result) { model.empty().append(result); })
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetOpenCATransaction()
{
    using (var context = new dbavlincacctgEntities())
    {
        catransList = context.CATransactions.ToList();                
    }
    return PartialView("_CATransaction", catransList);
}
```

Partial View

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>CA Number</th>
            <th>Requestor</th>
            <th>Payee</th>
            <th>Total CA Amount</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.TransID</td>
                    <td>@item.TransactionNumber</td>
                    <td>@item.RequestorID</td>
                    <td>@item.Payee</td>
                    <td>@item.TotalAmount</td>
                    <td>@item.Status</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary">View</button> <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code display the integer RequestorID(obviously since I call it from the Model). I don't have any idea on how to display the FirstName from other Model using FK. I used EF6 if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Show us the definition of your entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I've got it now. Thanks to Kovid Purohit for giving me ideas. It was solved by

```
public partial class Employee
{
  public <DataType> EmpID {get; set;}
  public <DataType> FirstName {get; set;}
  public <DataType> LastName {get; set;}
}
public partial class Requestor
{
  public <DataType> RequestorID {get; set;}
  public <DataType> EmpID {get; set;}

  public virtual Employee Employee {get; set;}
}
public partial class Transaction
{
  public <DataType> TransID {get; set;}
  public <DataType>  RequestorID {get; set;}
  public <DataType> Amount {get; set;}
  public <DataType> TransType {get; set;}

  public virtual Requestor Requestor{get; set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetOpenCATransaction()
{
    using (var context = new dbavlincacctgEntities())
    {
        catransList = context.CATransactions.ToList();                
    }
    return PartialView("_CATransaction", catransList);
}
```

Partial View:

```
<tbody>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.TransID</td>
                    <td>@item.TransactionNumber</td>
                    <td>@item.Requestor.Employee.Firstname</td>
                    <td>@item.Payee</td>
                    <td>@item.TotalAmount</td>
                    <td>@item.Status</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary">View</button> <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You'll need to change your Model to include field(s) from the Employee - declare a ViewModel.
2. Depending on how the entites are set up, you can query and pull up data from related entities either directly (foreign key relation) or indirectly by fetching the related entities and doing the Join yourself in LINQ.

Look at [Loading Related Entities EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data), specifically the Explicit loading section from where you may be able to either use the `Collection` method or the `Reference` method, **depending on your entity setup**.

3. Finally you may as well Join the data, if there is no support in your entity classes.
4. Once the data includes the Employee information, it is relatively trivial to display it and it looks like you already know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do this directly using LINQ joins

```
var firstName=(from trans in context.CATransactions join req in context.Requestor on trans.RequestorID equals req.RequestorId join emp in context.employees on req.EmpID equals emp.EmpId Select new {emp.FirstName} ).ToList();
```

or you can change your Model Like this:

```
public class Employee
{
  public <DataType> EmpID {get; set;}
  public <DataType> FirstName {get; set;}
  public <DataType> LastName {get; set;}
}
public class Requestor
{
  public <DataType> RequestorID {get; set;}
  public Employee EmpID {get; set;}
}
public class Transaction
{
  public <DataType> TransID {get; set;}
  public Requestor  RequestorID {get; set;}
  public <DataType> Amount {get; set;}
  public <DataType> TransType {get; set;}

}
```

So after implementing this you can query

```
var data=context.CATransactions.Select(a=>a.RequestorID.EmpID.FirstName).ToList();
```

Comment: Kindly Support me by Upvoting my answer. I would really appreciate your this effort.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Support me by Upvoting my answer. I would really appreciate your this effort.